# Mixing a Table with Angular-UI Accordion

Tags: angularjs, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to mix a table with angular-ui's accordion but I can't figure out a way to do it.
I'm not a pro, writing directives. I wonder if such a bridge exist. To achieve something like this :

```
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed" thead>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>{{ data.profile.firstname }}</th>
            <th>{{ data.profile.lastname }}</th>
            <th>{{ data.profile.email }}</th>
            <th>{{ data.profile.company_name }}</th>
            <th>{{ data.profile.city }}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody accordion close-others="true">
        <!-- <tr ng-repeat="client in clients" ng-click="goTo('profile/' + client.username);"> -->
        <tr ng-repeat="client in clients" accordion-group is-open="client.isOpen">
            <accordion-heading>
                <td>{{ client.firstname }}</td>
                <td>{{ client.lastname }}</td>
                <td>{{ client.email }}</td>
                <td>{{ client.company_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ client.city }}</td>
            </accordion-heading>
            Accordion Content
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Though it's not working :( Is there anyone who succeded to achieve something like this ?

The result I'm looking for is for when I click on a line in the table, it does the same behavior of an accordion.

Answer (score 9):

In my case I made it a bit primitive but maybe that would be a good solution for you as well. Look:

```
 <tbody ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy:predicate:reverse"  >
  <tr ng-click="isOpen=!isOpen">
    <td>{{person.name}}</td>
    <td>{{person.job}}</td>
    <td>{{person.age}}</td>
    <td>{{person.grade}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-if="isOpen">
  <td>Just an empty line</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: To make sure only a single accordion stays open at a time,declare this in your Ctrl (inspired by Mohideen ibn Mohammed below):

$scope.expanded = {l1: -1};

Then you can do something like this(you can use l2 etc for additional levels):

<tbody ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy:predicate:reverse"  >
  <tr ng-click="expanded.l1 = ($index === expanded.l1) ? -1 : $index">
    <td>{{person.name}}</td>
    <td>{{person.job}}</td>
    <td>{{person.age}}</td>
    <td>{{person.grade}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-if="expanded.l1 === $index">
  <td>Just an empty line</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>

Answer (score 4):

1) You can try `div` instead of `table` for main accordion. It works for me.

2) And here is the `accordion` `table` example done in JSFiddle below, i hope it will help you. http://jsfiddle.net/Pixic/VGgbq/

Comment: Links to external sites without explanations in the stack overflow answer are generally discouraged. Explain the solution here with relevant snippets of code. Link to the fiddle as a way to see it all in action.