# Accordion div inside each tr of a html table using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a scenario where I need to make all `tr` of a html table as an accordion. where the collapse pane should be a `div` which needs to be present below each `tr`. I have to use ng-repeat on `tr` to construct the table. 
need something like this

```
..
<tr ng-repeat='row in rows'>
<div ng-repeat='row in rows'>
..
```

where the html should render as below

```
<tr> //row[0]
<div> //row[0]
<tr> //row[1]
<div> //row[1]
<tr> //row[2]
<div> //row[2]
```

is it possible to have `div` as `tr` sibling if yes how to achieve above scenario? if not how can we approach this scenario?
any idea will be appreciated

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588753/mixing-a-table-with-angular-ui-accordion

Comment: @nishantagrawal link somehow helped me to understand more on the scenario though it didn't give me the answer. thanks.

Comment: did you go through the jsfiddle in the answer. it is implemented nicely.

Comment: yeah. having a `div` as sibling of `tr` seems impossible as far as I gathered from forums. So I need to somehow have a `tr` instead of `div` in my code