# angular 6: How to make expandable table with ngfor?

Tags: html, angular

I have a table in angular 6. This is working find, But I want to use it in ngfor and it not working as expected. Here is the table:

```css
  .hiddenRow {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Credit</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1" class="accordion-toggle" style="cursor: pointer;">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>05 May 2013</td>
          <td>Credit Account</td>
          <td class="text-success">$150.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="12" class="hiddenRow">
            <div class="accordian-body collapse jumbotron" id="demo1">
              Demo1
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

This is working find except that I want to include `*ngFor` in order to loop on many elements. Any idea ?

Comment: post the array u want to loop \

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka I to loop on simple array like [0, 1, 2, 3] with the exact same row.

Comment: is this a repeat of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588753/mixing-a-table-with-angular-ui-accordion ? using an accordion instead of a hidden row?

Answer (score 1):

Put this instead of the table row you want to repeat for each row

```
<tr *ngFor="for row of rows">
  <td> {{row.id}} </td>
  <td> {{row.date}} </td>
  <td> {{row.desc}} </td>
  <td> {{row.credit}} </td>
</tr>
```

(this code is not tested)

Comment: I want to repeat to rows, please look carefully my table.

Answer (score -1):

**Update**

Try this:

```
<table class="table table-condensed" *ngFor="let l of list_name" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Description<th>
        <th>Credit</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  ...
```

You can iterate over an array with your desired length

Comment: please look carefully my question